# PHP convert one dimensional array into multidimensional

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have one array as

```
$tmpArr =  array('A', 'B', 'C');
```

I want to process this array and want new array as

```
$tmpArr[A][B][C] = C
```

I.e last element becomes the value of final array.

Can anyone suggest the solution? Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: this does not make sense

Comment: id on't think this makes any sense, too, but if you wan't help, please provide a little more information - what schould happen is the input inrray has more/less than 3 elements? what have you tried till now? why do yau have to do this transformation and can't do it like you need when you're creating the array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Iterate the array of keys and use a [reference](http://php.net/language.references) for the end of the chain:

```
$arr = array();
$ref = &$arr;
foreach ($tmpArr as $key) {
    $ref[$key] = array();
    $ref = &$ref[$key];
}
$ref = $key;
$tmpArr = $arr;
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  I had almost exactly the same thing (the only difference is the variable names)...  +1

Answer (score 10):

```
$tmpArr =  array('A', 'B', 'C');
$array = array();
foreach (array_reverse($tmpArr) as $arr)
      $array = array($arr => $array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [B] => Array
                (
                    [C] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$tmpArr[$tmpArr[0]][$tmpArr[1]][$tmpArr[2]] = $tmpArr[2];
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: yes, exactly. But I want it dynamic I.e number of elements are not fixed. it may vary.