# PHP. How to convert simple array into multidimensional with single parent

Tags: php

I have
`$x = array('a', 'b', 'c');`

I need to convert this to:

```
array (size=1)
  'a' => 
    array (size=1)
      'b' => 
        array (size=1)
          'c' => boolean true
```

I need to create multidimensional array with single child\parent, first one will be the main\root key of array (it's 'a') the last one's value should be 'bool true', that's all i need

Pleas help, thank u

Comment: It is impossible to answer to this, since the conversion rules are completely vague.

Comment: `c` is not `boolean` it is a `string` your example. You could do `$x = array('a', 'b', 'c' => true);`. Your question is unclear though.

Comment: Okay sorry for low amount of info, i need to create multidimensional array with single child\parent, first one will be the main parent (it's 'a') the last one's value should be 'bool true', that's all i need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP convert one dimensional array into multidimensional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804062/php-convert-one-dimensional-array-into-multidimensional)

Comment: This is a typical X => Y Problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why do you need to do that but this should help:

```
function transform($array)
{
 if (empty($array)) {
  return true;
 }

 return [array_shift($array) => transform($array)];
}
```

Comment: Upvoted this; whilst it's a vague question this is a nice approach.

Comment: Thank u very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$tmpArr = array('a', 'b', 'c');
$arr = array();
$ref = &$arr;
foreach ($tmpArr as $key) {
    $ref[$key] = array();
    $ref = &$ref[$key];
}
$ref = true;
$tmpArr = $arr;
print '<pre>';print_r($tmpArr);
print '<pre>';var_dump($tmpArr);
exit;
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

var_dump result:

```
array(1) {
  ["a"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["b"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["c"]=>
      &bool(true)
    }
  }
}
```